# How to distinguish between temporary and long-term hate/hating?

Tags: ambiguity

When I say I hate someone in could be in a heat of a moment. "I hate him." (right now, because he ate my chocolate). However I could "I hate snakes." (all my life).

It is still the same word.

Are there synonyms we could use to distinguish the meaning? Or some other way?

Comment: I dunno, but you did a pretty good job in your question of distinguishing the two. But for a period such as "lifelong" you could use **I have a standing hatred of snakes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any synonyms to the word hate generally have to do with describing the intensity of the feeling, not so much as to how long it lasts. One could assume that the more intense it is the longer it lasts, but this can be, as you've pointed out, unclear.

It is also a stylistic choice to impulsively say "I hate him." (temporarily, becuase he ate my chocolate) or instead the tamer "I'm mad at him." Personally I think "I'm mad at him." is truer to the context for a 'he stole my candy bar' situation, unless the person in general becomes easily enraged over such a thing. Again this is in regards to the person's personality.

If I had to rate words based on intensity it'd go like this (from least intense to most intense):

1. Aversion
2. Dislike
3. Disgust
4. Detest
5. Hate
6. Despise
7. Loathe
8. Abhor
9. Execrate

You could also provide more detail and in writing this is important. There's a difference between "I hate snakes." and "He has a life long hatred of snakes."

To see it in action I recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86jbnMOAcy0).